# Generate Designer.cs files from resx files

Tags: c#, resgen

This is driving me crazy. What's wrong with the following command? I think I'm using the right syntax for resgen, and for the hell of me I can't figure out why I'm getting the exception I'm getting. Can anybody help?

[image: seriously: WTF?]

Comment: What happens when you try putting quotes around your full path?  It seems that the command is getting confused about where to parse, quotes can help that.

Comment: Also, I am assuming that "namespace", "className", and "className.cs" are in fact real names and files

Comment: Do you have multiple versions of Visual Studio Installed?....the .NET SDK? .....which RESGEN version are you actually using. Are you on a 64bit OS?